# System.linq.Dynamic.DynamicQuerable.OrderBy has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to order the result of a multiple table join by a sting variable "sortCriteria". The code work fine in the Sql version using ERD, but throws an error in this Xml version. Could anyone give me some hints ? Thanks

The error: '**System.linq.Dynamic.DynamicQuerable.OrderBy(System.Linq.iQuerable,string,param object[]) has some invalid arguments**'

---

Thanks

```
 public ActionResult WebGrid(string sort = "OrderID", string sortDir = "ASC", int rowsPerPage = 10, int page = 1)
    {

        string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data");
        var Customers = XElement.Load(path + @"\XCustomers.xml").
    Elements("Customer").
    Select(x => new CustomerModel(
        (string)x.Element("CustomerID"),
        (string)x.Element("CompanyName"),
        (string)x.Element("ContactName")

    )).ToList();

        var employees=XElement.Load(path + @"\XEmployees.xml").
    Elements("Employee").
    Select(x => new EmployeeModel(
        (int)x.Element("EmployeeID"),
        (string)x.Element("FirstName"),
        (string)x.Element("LastName")

    )).ToList();

       var orderDetails = XElement.Load(path + @"\XOrderDetails.xml").
    Elements("OrderDetail").
    Select(x => new OrderDetailModel(
        (int)x.Element("OrderID"),
        (int)x.Element("Quantity"),
        (decimal)x.Element("UnitPrice")

    )).ToList();

        var orders = XElement.Load(path + @"\XOrders.xml").
    Elements("Order").
    Select(x => new OrderModel(
        (int)x.Element("OrderID"),
        (string)x.Element("CustomerID"),
        (int)x.Element("EmployeeID")

    )).ToList();


        ViewBag.sort = sort;
        ViewBag.sortDir = sortDir;
        ViewBag.rowsPerPage = rowsPerPage;
        ViewBag.page = page;
        ViewBag.count = orders.Count();

        var sortCriteria = string.Format("{0} {1}, OrderID {1}", sort, sortDir);

        var grouping = orderDetails.GroupBy(t => t.OrderID).Select(c => new { OrderID = c.Key, Price = c.Sum(w => w.UnitPrice), Quantity = c.Sum(e => e.Quantity) });



        var result = orders.Join(Customers, o => o.CustomerID, c => c.CustomerID, (o, c) =>
   new { o.OrderID, o.EmployeeID, c.CompanyName, c.ContactName }).Join(employees, oc => oc.EmployeeID, e => e.EmployeeID, (oc, e)
   => new { oc.OrderID, oc.CompanyName, oc.ContactName, Name = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName, }).Join(grouping, oce => oce.OrderID,
   od => od.OrderID, (oce, od) => new MyModel
   {
       OrderID = oce.OrderID,
       ContactName = oce.ContactName,
       CompanyName = oce.CompanyName,
       EmployeeName = oce.Name,
       TotalQuantity = (int)od.Quantity,
       TotalPrice = (int)od.Price
   }).OrderBy(sortCriteria).Skip((page - 1) * rowsPerPage)
           .Take(rowsPerPage);
        return View(result );
    }

}
```

Comment: Adding the actual error message would most likely help.

Comment: As would formatting the code in a more readable fashion.

Comment: Maybe the LINQ-to-XML provider doesn't like you specifying OrderID as a sort key twice? If that's not it, then what you really should be doing here is simplifying the code example down to something that someone could actually copy locally and run.